# Make Logical Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to make a logical diagram like that : 
[image: diagram]

mirror image : https://pasteboard.co/HicPswl.png

But I don't want to add picture with \includegraphics... I have no experience diagrams in latex. Can you give an example code ? I find some example in circuit diagram TikZ package. But I could not find similar above diagram. Thanks for your help.

My attempt and result :

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,fill=blue!20,minimum size=2em]
% diameter of semicircle used to indicate that two lines are not connected
\def\radius{.7mm} 
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,fill=blue!10,minimum size=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US, huge circuit symbols]

\node[block] at (0,0) (block1) {Sınıf diğer sınıfların niteliklerine erişmekte \newline
ATFD > 3};
\node[block] at (0,2) (block2) {Sınıfın fonksiyonel karmaşıklığı fazla
\newline
WMC >= 47};
\node[block] at (0,4) (block3) {Sınıf diğer sınıfların niteliklerine erişmekte \newline
ATFD > 3};

\node[and gate US, draw, rotate=0] at (7,2) (And1) {};

\draw[->] (block1) -- (And1);
\draw[->] (block2) -- (And1);
\draw[->] (block3) -- (And1);
\node[block] at (9,2) (Result) {God Class};
\draw[->] (And1) -- (Result);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

result : https://pasteboard.co/HidxBjn.png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Basically circuitikz is able to draw the logical gates you need and provides the anchor points to connect with arbitrary TikZ nodes, so please have a try and post your attempt here (as minimal compilable code example).

Comment: @TeXnician I post my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
\node[draw,align=center] (box1) at (-2,2) {Some centered tex \\ with math \\ \\ $\sin(\pi)$};
\node[draw,align=center] (box2) at (-2,0) {Some centered tex \\ with math \\ \\ $\sin(\pi)$};
\node[draw,align=center] (box3) at (-2,-2) {Some centered tex \\ with math \\ \\ $\sin(\pi)$};
\node [and gate] (a1) at (1,0) {VE};
\node[draw] (a2) at (3,0) {other node};

\draw (box1.east) -|++(1mm,-1mm)|- ([yshift=1mm]a1.west);
\draw (box3.east) -|++(1mm,1mm)|- ([yshift=-1mm]a1.west);
\draw(box2) -- (a1);
\draw (a1) -- (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The rest you can find it either in the manual or searching on this site.